# Flutter Codemagic - Trouble Publishing

Tags: android, ios, flutter, codemagic

I am trying to publish my App, but am struggling at the Publishing part.

When it is building on Android, everything goes smoothly and seems to pass, moving to building on iOS.

Even though it also appears to go smoothly, it gives the following message

```
Running Xcode build...
Xcode archive done.                     350.4s
Built /Users/builder/clone/build/ios/archive/Runner.xcarchive.
Building App Store IPA...               41.8s
Built IPA to /Users/builder/clone/build/ios/ipa.
To upload to the App Store either:    
     1. Drag and drop the "build/ios/ipa/*.ipa" bundle into the Apple Transport macOS app https://apps.apple.com/us/app/transporter/id1450874784    
     2. Run "xcrun altool --upload-app --type ios -f build/ios/ipa/*.ipa --apiKey your_api_key --apiIssuer your_issuer_id". 
        See "man altool" for details about how to authenticate with the App Store Connect API key.
```

It then proceeds to the Publishing part, where it fails, and the information given is:

```
Failed to publish App.ipa to App Store Connect.
Google Play failed to upload artefacts. Changes cannot be sent for review automatically. Please set the query parameter changesNotSentForReview to true. Once committed, the changes in this edit can be sent for review from the Google Play Console UI.: 
  { 
   "error": {       
      "code": 400,        
      "message": "Changes cannot be sent for review automatically. Please set the query parameter changesNotSentForReview to true. Once committed, the changes in this edit can be sent for review from the Google Play Console UI.",        
      "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
    }
  }
```

Regardless of the message about Google Play failing to upload artefacts, I don't understand what that has to do with the .ipa file failing to publish on App Store Connect.

I am not used to using Codemagic, but, on the build before this, everything went down okay, and nothing has changed since then.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue with codemagic.yaml file configuration, the solution as the error message says was to add this line

```
changes_not_sent_for_review: true
```

in the google_play section
So the google_play section looks like this

```
google_play:
        credentials: $GCLOUD_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_CREDENTIALS
        track: internal
        changes_not_sent_for_review: true
```

Another solution I think is to disable managed posts on play google play console.

hope this will help.